# HP Laptop built in bluetooth cant find headphones, but bluetooth usb can

Tags: windows, windows-10, bluetooth, ubuntu-16.04, elementaryos

I have a HP laptop (HP probook 4530s) that wont find my bluetooth headphone via the built in bluetooth device.

I do have a usb bluetooth device that will pick up the headphones and will allow me to use them with the laptop, however I would perfer to keep this usb connected to my desktop.

I have both windows 10 and elementary os (ubuntu 16.04.3) installed. Both can't find it.

Any ideas why the built in device does not work?

Comment: If neither OS can see it then 1. it's not compatible (Bluetooth version or other issue) *or* 2. it's defective.

Comment: The Probook 4530s uses one of three internal BT modules, that are BT 2.1+EDR or 3.0. The BT version should not be the issue.

Comment: Any linux commands I can run to see supported bluetooth versions?

Comment: @user3906878 [Linux - Bluetooth version of connected devices – Gordon Lesti](https://gordonlesti.com/linux-bluetooth-version-of-connected-devices/)

Comment: @user3906878 [how to check bluetooth version on my laptop](//askubuntu.com/q/591803)

Comment: running the command shows HCI Version: 3.0 (0x5) Revision: 0x1aa1, the headphones are Skullcandy Hesh 2 Wireless